# 'CalledProcessError' exit status 128. Git describe ERROR and sed in sh() to replace '/' by '__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

i am calling this command :     `GITID=sh( 'git describe --dirty --long --tags --abbrev=10 | sed -e "s:/:__:g"' ).strip()`
by python subprocess.Popen

```
try:
    # Check file can be read: throws exception if cannot be read
    f = open(self.path, "r")

    # Calls nyq to process yaml: throws exception if exit code!=0 => check=True

    # TODO : use object, as soon as nyq becomes part of mcook legacy code
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["nyq", self.path, str('regressions.' + self.regressionName)],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf8')
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()

    # TODO : Add check for nyq execution exit code
    if proc.returncode != 0:
        logging.error(
            "Error executing nyq ({})".format(proc.returncode))
        raise Exception(stdout)

    # Creates YAML object from output of nyq: throws exception if content is not a valid YAML stream
    list_files = stdout
    self.parsed_data = yaml.load(list_files)  # load EMC data
except Exception as exc:
    logging.error("An error occured during nested YAML processing:")
    logging.error(exc)
    sys.exit(1)
```

can't understand why i am getting this error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX3mY.png)

Resolved :
GITID=sh( 'git describe --dirty --long --tags --abbrev=10').replace('/', '__').strip()

Using replace instead of sed!

Comment: Note: whenever possible, copy the actual error text, rather than showing an image of it. See [ask].

Comment: You are reinventing `subprocess.check_output()` needlessly. Like the documentation says, avoid `subprocess.Popen()` when you can; adding a large amount of boilerplate code is ugly and error-prone, and completely unnecessary when the standard library already contains a correct version of that boilerplate in a tested, documented, easy-to-use higher-level function.

Comment: `sed -e "s:/:__:g"` is trivial to reimplement in Python anyway; `GITID=subprocess.check_output['git', 'describe', '--dirty', '--long', '--tags', '--abbrev=10']).replace('/', '__').strip()`

Comment: The error message (in an obscure low-contrast image - ***pretty please*** [don’t do that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)) reveals that you are calling a shell pipeline without `shell=True`.

Answer (score 0):

> i am calling this command : `GITID=sh( 'git describe --dirty --long --tags --abbrev=10 | sed -e "s:/:__:g"' ).strip()` by python subprocess.Popen

I don't think you are—at least, not in the code you are showing here.  I think you are calling `nyq` here:

> ```
> proc = subprocess.Popen(["nyq", ...], ...)
> ```

What `nyq` does, subsequently, is up to `nyq` itself, in code you *haven't* shown, and that code is almost certainly more important for the error.  If that code contains a `subprocess.Popen`, that could explain the rest of the error text.  Note that `subprocess.Popen` by default does *not* run the command through a shell; as a result, the command *cannot* contain pipe directives and further subprocess invocations.

You can, if you trust the strings in the command line a great deal, add `shell=True` to the `subprocess.Popen` invocation.  **See the [security considerations section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) of the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) before doing this.**